# How to select first one from the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, children

I have this 4 questions that are looping:
HTML is like this.

```
    <div class="question>

    <div>
     </div>
    <div class="question" id="question">
    <h1></h1>
    // conent inside
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
```

So everything before question is looping for whatever questions I have.
Now I want to select first question and add a class and remove the class.

When I say:

```
$(function() {
   $('.question').children().eq(0).addClass('hide');

});
```

It selects one below. when I do:

```
$(function() {
   $('.questions').children().eq(0).addClass('hide');

});
```

Then it selects all the question divs.

```
JS:



        if(data.questions) {
            quiz.set("questions", data.questions);
        }
        queueRender();
    }

    out.prototype.addQuestions = function(questions) {
        var _this = this;
        $.each(questions, function(i, v){
            _this.addQuestion(v);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Please add the failed script. How do you create an array?

Comment: We need more code.

Comment: $('#question').children().eq(0) would be how to access the first element inside that div.

Comment: I have added more to show you how questions are shown...
@MXMXCII
$('#question').children().eq(0)  -- it selects the first h1 inside the div that I want to select...

Comment: Just to clarify `<div class="question" id="question">` contains `<div class="quiz">`?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - Other way around: <div class="quiz"> contains <div class="question" id="question"> .

Comment: SO inserting duplicate ID is invalid HTML in that case...don't do that.

Comment: Sure thanks, but that's not an answer to my problem. @MarkSchultheiss

Answer (score 0):

Your post is less than 100% clear so to simply take guess at it:

Given this markup:

```
<div id="quiz">
  <div class="question">
    <h1>one</h1> content 1
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <h1>two</h1> content 2
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <h1>three</h1> content 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Add 'hide' class to all questions, then remove from first one:

```
$(function() {
 $('#quiz').find('.question').addClass('hide').eq(0).removeClass('hide');
});
```

Verbose version:

```
$(function() {
  $('#quiz').find('.question').addClass('hide');
  $('#quiz').find('.question').eq(0).removeClass('hide');
});
```

alternate verbose

```
$(function() {
  $('#quiz').find('.question').addClass('hide');
  $('#quiz').find('.question').first().removeClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: THANKS. Alright, so I mixed some things and I got my correct answer, that is:
$(function() {  
 var question = $('.questions').find('.question').eq(0);
  question.addClass('hide');

});

How do I find the next one on that?
add next()?

Comment: Not following your desire but `$('.questions').find('.question').eq(1);` is the "next one" IF it exists.  or `$('.questions').find('.question').each(...` to iterate over them.

Comment: Thanks. Btw the first thing only worked in Mozilla. Any idea why it doesn't work on other browsers?Sorry for so many questions!

Comment: dumb on my part, typing fast did not put id on the markup - fixed that